# How to substitute into a regular expression group in Python

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> s = 'foo: "apples", bar: "oranges"'
>>> pattern = 'foo: "(.*)"'
```

I want to be able to substitute into the group like this:

```
>>> re.sub(pattern, 'pears', s, group=1)
'foo: "pears", bar: "oranges"'
```

Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: Your pattern uses the greedy operator `.*`, meaning it will get the longest match it can find, which means that in your case the group will be `apples", bar: "oranges`. You're looking for `(.*?)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me works something like:

```
rx = re.compile(r'(foo: ")(.*?)(".*)')
s_new = rx.sub(r'\g<1>pears\g<3>', s)
print(s_new)
```

Notice `?`in re, so it ends with first `"`, also notice `"` in groups 1 and 3 because they must be in output.

Instead of `\g<1>` (or `\g<number>`) you can use just `\1`, but remember to use "raw" strings and that `g<1>` form is preffered because `\1` could be ambiguous (look for examples in [Python doc](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)) .

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r'(?<=foo: ")[^"]+(?=")', 'pears', s)
```

The regex matches a sequence of chars that

- Follows the string `foo: "`,
- doesn't contain double quotation marks and
- is followed by `"`

`(?<=)` and `(?=)` are [lookbehind and lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups/2973609#2973609)

This regex will fail if the value of `foo` contains escaped quots. Use the following one to catch them too:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=foo: ")(\\"|[^"])+(?=")', 'pears', s)
```

Sample code

```
>>> s = 'foo: "apples \\\"and\\\" more apples", bar: "oranges"'
>>> print s
foo: "apples \"and\" more apples", bar: "oranges"
>>> print   re.sub(r'(?<=foo: ")(\\"|[^"])+(?=")', 'pears', s)
foo: "pears", bar: "oranges"
```

Comment: This returns `'foo: "pears"'`

Comment: @lacopo That was a typo - try with the updated regex. Replaced `[^=]` with `[^"]`. Be warned that this will fail if the value of `foo` contains escaped quotation marks.

Comment: @lacopo updated the regex to handle escaped double quotes too.

Comment: Though now it would fail with a string like "a backslash:\\" -- there's no really robust way to match escaped strings with a regex unfortunately.

Comment: hmm.. I didn't think of that case.